# what is use of public function with body in abstract class of php?

Tags: php, methods, abstract-class, abstract

I have create one abstract class and declare two public functions and one abstract function. 
After that I have created body for public function in abstract class but when I extending this class to Another class what the method body does not call then I want to know what is use of public methods with body class.

```
<?php
         //declare abstract class
        abstract class Test {

    // declare method 1 with body
             public function method1()
             {
                 echo "hello"; //what is use of this code here
             }

             public function method2()
             {
                 $this->method3();
             }

            abstract public function method3();
         }

         //extended abstract class to another class
         class AnotherTest extends Test{

             public function method1(){
                 echo "5+9"/2;
             }

            public function method3(){
                 echo 2+9;
             }

             public function method2()
             {
                 echo "just for testing";
             }
         }

         $obj = new AnotherTest();

         $obj->method1(); 
         echo nl2br("\n");
         $obj->method3(9,10);
          echo nl2br("\n");
         $obj->method2();
        ?>
```

Comment: Well if you didn't override them it would call the method you declared in `Test`.. But you should rather read up a bit more on OO to fully understand why and how this works.

Comment: Best to go and RTM http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Answer (score 2):

Writing a method body for a method of a base class provides a "default" behavior for that method on any subclasses that don't override the method.

For any (non-`final`) `public` or `protected` method of a base class you can do one of the following:

- Accept that default behavior without modification by not defining a method with the same name in a subclass
- Override and wrap that behavior by defining a new method with the same name  that calls `parent::methodName()` in a subclass
- Override and replace that behavior by defining a new method with the same name that does NOT call `parent::methodName()` in a subclass

The major benefit of code written like this is that it takes advantage of [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) to dispatch generic method calls to specific implementations. **Defining a method body instead of leaving it abstract just provides a default behavior.** As this is a very abstract object-oriented programming concept, it is hard to set up an example that is both simple and not trivial. Best to look at popular codebases such as the [Laravel Framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework) or one of the various [Symfony components](https://github.com/symfony) for examples of this concept in action.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you would not normally `override` every abstract method. If you are then you're doing something wrong and need to refactor.

Also, having the abstract (or any extended class) gives you the ability to call `parent::function()` which will let the parents method run then you can do your current classes additional logic.

In the end this is the basis for `Polymorphism` simple explanation a child class can extend a parent but act differently by changing how methods behave.

Bluntly your "Test" are just bad examples because in those cases you're right the abstract bodies are almost pointless.